# Ubuntu 16.04 Wont Boot

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 system that will not boot anymore. I do see the GRUB boot loader but none of the options work. I always get an error: file '/vmlinuz-4.4.0.57-generic.efi.signed' not found

I am ok if I need to rebuild this machine if it comes to that but I need to get the data off of it which stored on an encrypted partition of this system. Looking for ideas on how to fix the boot issue or to access the encrypted volume as the original user so I can access my home folder.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something has happened to your ubuntu kernel . 
You can try another kernel by going to the advanced options in the grub list and trying another one .

However if this doesn't work , try a live bootable usb stick with ubuntu . Hopefully you can still access the root directory of your existing system and save whatever you need before clean reinstall .

Comment: None of the other boot options work, they all come up with the same error. If I boot with a live usb I can see the encrypted volume and I can enter my password but then I cannot access my home folder because that is encrypted as well. If I try to run the commands to enter that encryption key it just says it was setup wrong (which I know is incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Trying another kernel from the "advanced" option in GRUB, as Sanjay Josh suggests, is worth trying. If that fails, you might want to try using my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive or CD-R. (The page to which I've linked includes images for both.) Unlike GRUB, rEFInd scans the system for available kernels at every boot, so it may pick up whatever kernel(s) are installed, assuming they haven't all been wiped out.

Once you've booted, I recommend doing this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
```

This should install various package updates, including the latest kernel, remove older kernels, and ensure GRUB is in a consistent state.

Comment: I tried boot-repair and that did not work